# One set of tests for each version of a microservices?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, bdd, microservices

With microservices do I need to create tests folders for each version of each service like this:

### A

```
- Services
  - users
     - v1
         - src
         - tests
             - functional
             - unit
             - integration
     - v2
         - src
         - tests
             - functional
             - unit
             - integration
     - v3
         - src
         - tests
             - functional
             - unit
             - integration
```

### B

```
- Services
    - users
       - v1
            - src
       - v2
            - src
       - v3
            - src
       - tests
            - functional
            - unit
            - integration
```

### C

```
- Services
   - users
      - v1
      - v2
      - v3
   - tests
      - functional
      - integration
      - unit
```

### D

```
- Services
   - users
      - v1
      - v2
      - v3
- Tests
    - functional
    - integration
    - unit
```

Comment: It's down to personal preference. There is no right way to do this. I would personally select A because it seems most logical but that's just my preference

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll end up with something like

```
- Solution
    - IntegrationTestsFolder
          -IntegrationTestsProject1
          -IntegrationTestsProject2
    - BusinessLayerProject
    - BusinessLayerTestProject
```

So you'll have the tests near the targeted code.

You're unlikely to have as many Integration test projects as you have unit, and they're probably not mapped 1 to 1 with the source projects, so you might want to nest them all inside a `IntegrationTests` folder.

As for versioning, do you really double/version everything? If you just end up with a couple of different versioned classes, you can probably target them individually in the actual Unit/Integration test.